# Submitting cart items to Paypal Cart Upload, no items get through

Tags: html, forms, paypal

When I submit this form, it tells me there are errors, i have tried submitting an "_xclick" but that doesnt take the individual items. What is wrong?!

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item 1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="8.5000">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item 1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="7.5000">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_2" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="businessmail-facilitator@address.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/Cart/RedirectFromPaypal">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost/Cart/CancelFromPaypal">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://localhost/Cart/NotifyFromPaypal">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="invoice">
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, was formatting on the AMOUNT. Each had to be to two decimals like a regular currency. D'oh!

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item 1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="8.50">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item 1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="7.50">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_2" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="businessmail-facilitator@address.com">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/Cart/RedirectFromPaypal">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost/Cart/CancelFromPaypal">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://localhost/Cart/NotifyFromPaypal">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="invoice">
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
```